# Problems with splash screen

Tags: c#, specflow, ui-testing

I am working on a project that is split across solutions. One provides a container that the other, and more, use to provide common functionality. I have a  test project in each of the solutions and this shares framework code from one to the other. I am using SpecFlow and Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting to produce the automated tests.

The second application, in a separate solution, is the current focus of development but the test framework set up, Before/After and most of the page models, are in the first app and I reference them to save re-writing in the second. The second application has implemented a splash screen and this is causing tests to fail as the search for any elements fails even though the application starts fine. The tests end up with a reference to the splash screen instead of the actual application. I can get around this by commenting out the code that produces the splash screen so I can work for now but does anyone know how to check that the tests have the correct reference when they run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to refresh the ApplicationUnderTest as the elements for the splash screen were the ones attempting to search.